# error executing some of bash commands in python subprocess.call while few of them works like charm

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell, subprocess

I am having an issue running bash commands from a python script. some of them works while others don't

`ls` command works

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls"])
```

but I want to close some ports, but below command, don't seem to work

```
from subprocess import call
call(['lsof -ti:9938,9955,9910,9988 | xargs kill'])
```

gives an error

```
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/amar/Documents/vKey_XenServer/vkey/architectures/Reactive/deamons/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amar/Documents/vKey_XenServer/vkey/architectures/Reactive/deamons/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    call(['lsof -ti:a9938,9955,9910,9988 | xargs kill'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

so I tried some of the commands, few were working and others were not

For instance, `top` command works

```
from subprocess import call
call(['top'])
```

but, `cd ..` does not

```
from subprocess import call
call(['cd ..'])
```

gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amar/Documents/vKey_XenServer/vkey/architectures/Reactive/deamons/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    call(['cd ..'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I may be asking a rudimentary question, but how do I differentiate which shell command will work in python.

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: everything should work , what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the command using PIPE , you need to redirect the output of one command to the input of other subprocess Popen class.

Below example should work for you

```
from subprocess import Popen
import shlex
input="lsof -ti:9938,9955,9910,9988"
command=shlex.split(input) #will split the command in list format
p1 = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["xargs", "kill"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

For detailed information you can refer here
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1):

" cd .." is not a command; the command is "cd", and ".." is its argument. Consider passing `["cd", ".."]`. Same with `lsof`.

Comment: it worked, thanks for this update but how do I make `lsof -ti:9938,9955,9910,9988 | xargs kill`  work ?

Comment: You can not do this with `call ` because there is a pipe involved.

Answer (score -1):

another simple way of killing multiple ports is

```
from subprocess import call
call('pkill 50000 , 50001 , 50002 , 50003', shell=True)
print 'ports are closed'
```